# PHP array iteration with key value pair

Tags: php

I want to iterate through an array with "$key => $value" pair but want to go up to the last but one item. I want to know how that is doable using foreach or any other function.

Here is why I want to do it.
The key in my array is the URL parameter and the value is the value of that parameter. Now I will be constructing the URL query as 
key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3

I will add the delimiter "&" in between each key-value but not at the end. To do that I wanted to go up to the last but one item by putting the delimiter and change the last one's delimiter to be blank string.

So please let me know how foreach can be used to go up to last but one item or get me a better solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to use `http_build_query`

```
   <?php
   $data = array('foo'=>'bar',
          'baz'=>'boom',
          'cow'=>'milk',
          'php'=>'hypertext processor');

   echo http_build_query($data) . "\n";
   // Output : foo=bar&baz=boom&cow=milk&php=hypertext+processor

   echo http_build_query($data, '', '&amp;');
   // Ouput: foo=bar&amp;baz=boom&amp;cow=milk&amp;php=hypertext+processor

   ?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Using `foreach` loop (Not recommended)

```
   <?php
   $ar_qs = array();
   foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
     $ar_qs[] = "$key=". urlencode($value);
   }
   echo $query_string = implode("&", $ar_qs);
   ?>
```